# Why do I get this 'function is not defined' error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add image upload functionality in my project and I want to call a jquery function on button click. But I keep getting this error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: image is not a function
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

This is my button:

```
<button id="upload" value="Change the picture" onclick="image()">Change the picture</button>
```

And this is my jquery function that resides in a js file:

```
function image() {
  var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('file', file_data);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php/welcome/upload_image' + '/' + ID, // point to server-side controller method
    dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the server
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post',
    success: function (response) {
      $('.messages').html(response); // display success response from the server
    },
    error: function (response) {
      $('.messages').html(response); // display error response from the server
    }
  });
});
```

PS: I am using CodeIgniter in my project.

Comment: How are you including the JS and jquery in your page?

Comment: Do you have an element with an `id` of `image` on the page?

Comment: I have included them at the bottom, right before the closing body tag. I haven't downloaded jquery, I'm using CDN.

Comment: Are there any other errors in your developer console? I see a syntax error with a trailing `)` in the code you gave.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, I do have one

Comment: @4castle No, this is the only error

Comment: @eli Try to resolve any errors on the page first. As others pointed out there is a closing bracket issue at least.

Comment: Is that your *entire* Javascript file? Any chance you have that function inside of something like `(function () { ... })();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function image(){
});
```

You have an extra `)` in your code. remove it.

```
function image(){
}
```

Comment: Ok, I removed the extra bracket and also changed the name of the function and the weirdest thing happened. I had to make a copy of the project to see that the error is gone and the file is uploaded . In the original project, even after making the changes, I still get the error.

Comment: the same exact error or a different one ? @eli

Comment: The same exact error @turmuka

Comment: are you sure this is the full syntax @eli This error MUST occur because you have done something wrong in the syntax. there is no way plain javascript won't see a function. can you please provide us with more code if you have any?

Comment: I made a copy of the updated project and the copy  is working fine so I don't think there is something wrong with js.